# How to create onclick event on pie slice of fusion charts

Tags: angular, typescript, fusioncharts

I have integrated the fusion pie chart with below code:

app.component.ts file

```
const data = {
  chart: {
    caption: "Checkout Programs",
    subcaption: "",
    showvalues: "1",
    showpercentintooltip: "0",
    numberprefix: "Serial:",
    enablemultislicing: "1",
    theme: "fusion"
  },

  data: [ 
{
  "label": "card",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "label": "Currency",
  "value": 2
}, {
  "label": "Holding",
  "value": 3
}, {
  "label": "Payment Network",
  "value": 4
}
 ]
};
```

and below lines in app.component.html file:

```
 <fusioncharts
    [width]="width"
    [height]="height"
    [type]="type"
    [dataFormat]="dataFormat"
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
    >
  </fusioncharts>
```

Image:

[image]

Now, I want to run some function if user clicks the pie chart slice (Onclick() event in pie chart slice). and I just want to get the label value inside the method. if user clicks "card" slice in pie chart then the method prints console.log(event); as "cards".

Can anyone help me to achieve this.

Comment: I have never used fusioncharts before, but is it not just a matter of referencing and using the events listed here: https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events. Probably entityClick?

Comment: It works. Thanks. I just used the above link and added events in the component.ts file and look good now. Thank you.. Please add it as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Theunis for point out an exact solution that I'm looking for.

Used the same code base that mentioned under **entityClick**:

Please refer below link:

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events

Thanks once again.

Comment: entityClick event is used for FusionMaps, you can use dataPlotClick event, which is more specific to pie chart

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Fusion Charts event reference page to find events available on the **fusioncharts** component. I’m not entirely sure what the coverage is for the Angular component, but it does seem to be implemented to some degree:

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events

It seems like the **entityClick** would satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **dataPlotClick** event, which is more specific to pie chart, Triggered when a data plot is clicked.

To know more about please [refer](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events#event-dataplotClick)

```
 const dataSource = {
  "chart": {
    "caption": "Countries With Most Oil Reserves]",
    "subcaption": "In BBL = One Billion barrels",
    "xaxisname": "Country",
    "yaxisname": "Reserves (In BBL)",
    "theme": "fusion"
  },
  "data": [{
      "label": "Venezuela",
      "value": "297"
    },
    {
      "label": "Saudi Arabia",
      "value": "268"
    },
    {
      "label": "Canada",
      "value": "172"
    },
    {
      "label": "Iran",
      "value": "150"
    },
    {
      "label": "UAE",
      "value": "98.63"
    }
  ]
};

FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  const myChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: "pie2d",
    renderAt: "chart-container",
    width: "100%",
    height: "500",
    dataFormat: "json",
    dataSource,

    events: {
      dataPlotClick: function(e) {
        console.log(" Pie slice clicked " + e.data.categoryLabel);
      }
    }

  }).render();
});
```

Refer demo [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzahgrpL/1/)